# Which pool class should i use prefork, eventlet or gevent in celery?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have 3 remote workers, each one is running with default pool (prefork) and single task.

A single task is taking 2 to 5 minutes for completion as it runs on many different tools and inserts database in ELK.

worker command:
**celery -A project worker -l info**

Which pool class should I use to make processing faster?

is there any other method to improve performance?

Comment: You should test all three on your jobs and use the one that fits best.

Answer (score 27):

funny that this question scrolled by.

We just switched from eventlet to gevent. Eventlet caused hanging broker connections which ultimately stalled the workers.

General tips:

- Use a higher concurreny if you're I/O bound, I would start with 25, check the cpu load and tweak from there, aim for 99,9% cpu usage for the process.
- you might want to use --without-gossip and --without-mingle if your workforce grows.
- don't use RabbitMQ as your result backend (redis ftw!), but RabbitMQ is our first choice when it comes to a broker (the amqp emulation on redis and the hacky async-redis solution of celery is smelly and caused a lot of grief in our past).

---

More advanced options to tune your celery workers:

- pin each worker process to one core to avoid the overhead of moving processes around (taskset is your friend)
- if one worker isn't always working, consider core-sharing with one or two other processes, use nice if one process has priority

Answer (score 2):

I use celery in my django project.
When use eventlet I got a lot of errors like

```
dns timeout
```

in `eventlet==0.25.2`

Another error:

```
GreenSSLSocket does not have a public constructor
```

in `eventlet==0.22.0`. So Sad.

So I replace eventlet with `gevent==20.6.2`, and Everything works perfectly